# Why does the function RangeUpdate() for a Fenwick Tree not giving the correct output?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, fenwick-tree

I've implemented Fenwick Tree (BIT) with a function RangeUpdate() to update (increment) every element into a range by some value. All other functions i've implemented works fine except this. It doesn't increment every element by the given value. What's wrong with this function? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int BIT[100000];

void initBIT(int *Array,int Size)
{
    for(int i=1; i<=Size; i++)
    {
        int Add=Array[i-1];
        int j=i;
        while(j<=Size)
        {
            BIT[j] += Add;
            j += (j & (-j));
        }
    }
}

int SumQuery(int Index)
{
    int Sum=0;
    while(Index>0)
    {
        Sum += BIT[Index];
        Index -= Index & (-Index);
    }
    return Sum;
}

int RangeSumQuery(int i,int j)
{
    return SumQuery(j)-SumQuery(i-1);
}

void Update(int Index, int Value, int Size)
{
    while(Index<=Size)
    {
        BIT[Index] += Value;
        Index += Index & (-Index);
    }
}

void RangeUpdate(int i, int j, int Value, int Size)
{
    Update(i,Value,Size);
    Update(j+1,-Value,Size);
}

int main()
{
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

    int a[10]={4,1,6,7,2,8,9,2,5,3};

    initBIT(a,10);
    cout<<SumQuery(4)<<endl;   //Output: 18; which is correct.
    cout<<RangeSumQuery(3,5)<<endl;   //Output: 15; which is correct.
    RangeUpdate(1,4,1,10);           //Tried to increment every element from range 1 to 4 by 1.
    cout<<SumQuery(4)<<endl;       //Output: 19; which is incorrect. Output should be 22. Every element from range 1 to 4 didn't get incremented by 1.

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the function `RangeUpdate(int i, int j, int Value, int Size)` not updating every element into the range?

Comment: Have you tested your `Update` function first?

Comment: Yes, I've checked. The Update function works fine. @Petr